# Como uso Skip e Take com o Helper PagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, paginação

Gostaria de fazer a paginação, mas utilizando `Skip` e `Take` no meu LINQ para não buscar todos os resultados.

Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
    public ViewResult Index(int? page)
    {

        var grupos= from s in db.grupos
                     select s;

        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(grupos.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

Como uso `Skip` e `Take` no meu LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como nossa amiga Maria apontou, você pode utilizar o `Skip()`e `Take()`, mas o `PagedList` já faz isso pra você.

A substituição seria:

```
int pageSize = 3;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

var grupos = db.grupos
                .Skip((pageSize - 1) * pageNumber)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .ToList();

return View(grupos);
```

Mas não é necessário, já que isso já é feito pra você internamente no `ToPagedList()`.

Answer (score 4):

Não existem os equivalentes a Take e Skip na sintaxe de query, mas você consegue usar os métodos fazendo uma mescla, da seguinte forma:

```
var grupos= (from s in db.grupos
             select s).Skip(10).Take(20);
```

Comment: Sim, mas de onde vem esses valores 10, 20 usando o Helper?

Comment: É um valor qualquer que usei como exemplo. Geralmente você calcula os valores de acordo com a página atual. No Skip você pode passar `(page - 1) * size` e no Take  apenas o size; onde page é a página atual e size a quantidade de registros apresentados.

Answer (score 2):

Internamente o `PagedList`, faz automáticamente o `Skip` e `Take`, e ele só traz os dados necessários para gerar a página. Em seu algoritmo ele calcula a quantidade de página e conforme o paramentro *page* traz a página correta que você precisa exibir!

Ou você usa sem ele e ai coloca `Skip` e `Take`, ou você utiliza `PagedList`, ou seja, os dois ao mesmo tempo não tem finalidade nenhuma, ou um (Skip e Take) ou outro (PagedList).